# Herkou deployment: OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file

Tags: heroku

My application was running fine in Heroku servers before. Then after just a certain update (mainly with shapely, rtree requirements - thus the need for libspatial libraries) it encounters an Application Error page.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. But I tried installing a so called Heroku Buildpack using the command:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/julienfr112
/libspatialindex-buildpack.git
```

The app restarts but encounters the same error. How can I fix this further? This seems to be a problem after insalling Rtree, geopandas etc. Libspatialindex is a requisite of RTree so I'm just not sure if I'm installing libspatialindex in Heroku correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

From Heroku Dashboard -> Settings scroll down to buildpacks, I found that it didn't add the libspatialindex buildpack from my terminal despite the success message. So I manually added it through here, redeploying with an empty commit and it should be okay looking like this during deployment:

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        64 static files copied to '/tmp/build_2fce321c986c6ddada9266ff904ed2b4/static', 73 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: -----> libspatialindex app detected
remote: -----> Installing LIBSPATIALINDEX
remote: -----> setting PATHS for LIBSPATIALINDEX
remote: -----> oki
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
```

Well I encountered another error but I think this is already outside this question. :)